# Mongo - sort an array of objects in subdocument

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose and I want to issue a sort when i get the data back:

```
        Model
            .findOne({_user: req.user._id, name: req.params.name})
            .sort({'music.vote': -1})
```

The data looks like this, I want to order the array of musics by vote DESC

```
    {
        "__v": 2,
        "_id": "5492bfaf59c17bdead8363c6",
        "_owner": "5491e02a9f5418da92bfb4e6",
        "createdAt": "2014-12-18T11:51:11.961Z",
        "updatedAt": "2014-12-18T11:51:30.965Z",
        "name": "list-one",        
        "music": [
            {
                "name": "music 1",
                "vote": 1,
                ...
            },
            {
                "name": "music 2",
                "vote": 5,
                ...
            }
        ],
        "_user": [
            "5491e02a9f5418da92bfb4e6"
        ]
    }
```

Comment: MongoDB doesn't sort arrays in documents for you as part of returning query results. Sort it client side, or you can store it in sorted order. See [$sort](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/#up._S_sort) for info and examples.

Answer (score 0):

This will vary slightly depending on your version of mongoose, but the method signature for findOne looks something like this:

```
function findOne(conditions, fields, options, callback)
```

as options (the sort), mongoose is handling as fields(which fields to load).

You might try explicitly passing null for fields:

```
Model.findOne({}, null, {sort: {music.vote: -1 }}, callback);
```